# How Sketchflow player works?

Tags: silverlight, sketchflow

If you launch a Sketchflow project, a SF player is hosting the sketched screens and interacts with them. The idea of one Silverlight application hosting another and interacting with it is very interesting to me.

Can someone point me to some posts/papers describing how this can be implemented? How the events raised in hosted application can be bubbled to the application "in charge"? Something with the application profiler funcionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work quite the way you are thinking. The main app is the SketchFlow Player app and the sketched screens are created in a control library that is used by the main app. There are not 2 separate apps in this case, just 1 main app, which uses resources compiled into a separate dll (the screens control library).

Comment: I see, I didn't realize it can be that simple. But I'm still curios about the "profiling" and hosting.